# What's the correct way to pass an object that will never change to an NSWindowController?

Tags: swift, nswindowcontroller

I have an `NSWindowController` that shows a table and uses another controller as the data source and delegate for an `NSTableView`. This second controller displays information from an object, which is passed in by the `NSWindowController`. That controller in turns has the object set as a property by the `AppDelegate`. It looks like this:

```
class SomeWindowController: NSWindowController {
    var relevantThing: Thing!
    var someTableController: SomeTableController!
    @IBOutlet weak var someTable: NSTableView!

    override func windowDidLoad() {
        someTableController = SomeTableController(thing: relevantThing)
        someTable.dataSource = someTableController
        someTable.delegate = someTableController
    }
}
```

In the `AppDelegate` I then do something like

```
func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
    relevantThing = Thing()
    someWindowController = SomeWindowController()
    someWindowController.relevantThing = relevantThing
    someWindowController.showWindow(nil)
}
```

Is this a reasonable approach? I feel like the implicitly unwrapped optionals used in `SomeWindowController` might be bad form. Also, `relevantThing` is not allowed to change in my case, so I feel a `let` would be more correct. Maybe the `relevantThing` should be made constant and passed in through the initializers? Or would that break the `init?(coder: NSCoder)` initializer?

I'd greatly appreciate any suggestions, as I'm trying to get a feel for the right way to do things in Swift.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few things:

Is there any reason your are creating your window controller in code and not loading it from a storyboard/xib?

Generally, a better practice is to put all your 'controller' that relates to a view in a `NSViewController` and use `NSWindowController` only for stuff that relates to the window itself (e.g. toolbar, window management, etc).

Similarly to iOS, `NSViewController` is now integrated into the window/view lifecycle and responder chain. For many windows you don't even need to subclass `NSWindowController`.

XCode's app project template creates a storyboard with the window, main view and their controllers. This is a good starting point.

`NSWindowController` has a `contentViewController` property that is set to the `NSViewController` of the main content view (when loaded from storyboard). You generally don't need a separate view controller property for your view controller.

I think that usually, you want to minimize modifying your controllers from outside code and make them as independent as possible. This makes them more testable and reusable.

If your `Thing` instance is global for the entire application (as it appears from your code), you may want to consider adding it as a singleton instance to the `Thing` class and retrieving it from the `NSViewController` (e.g in `viewDidLoad()`)

If you put your controllers/views in storyboard, you can connect the table's datasource/delegate there. And if this your main window, it can load and show it automatically when the app starts. But in any case, put your `NSViewController`/View wiring in the view controller.

If you want to separate logic between your main NSViewController into a more specialized view controller that handles a specific part of your view, you can use `NSContainerView` in Interface Builder to add additional view controllers to handle specific views.

Comment: Thanks, you've convinced me to check out storyboards and they're definitely the way forward. Appreciate it!